# Stack Site Monitor for iPhone/iPad

Tags: app, iphone, ipad

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

Main Windows
[image: Main Window]

Select Site
[image: Select Site]

Detail Stats
[image: Detail Stats]

### About

From this app for iPhone, iPod touch and iPad you can monitor Stack Sites.

#### License

I am in the process of putting in the App Store

#### Download

[Product Page](http://www.lcp.com.ar/node/4)

#### Platform

Objective-C
iPhone OS

### Contact

- Leonardo Carlos Prada - aka Jedi
  Master Spooky - lprada@lcp.com.ar
- https://lcp.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W19
- http://lcp.fogbugz.com/

### Code

Objective-C
[StackKit](https://stackapps.com/questions/346/stackkit-an-api-framework-for-cocoa)

Any help with the Testing and Ideas are welcome

Comment: So does this app let you browse the actual questions?

Comment: No, it only monitor the Sites, I am developing another for that.

Answer (score 2):

Looks nice.

I just did the same thing as a simple demo of SOAPI-JS wrapper.  You can see it [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/494/soapi-js-fluent-javascript-client-library-for-the-stack-exchange-api/513#513).

Is not pretty like yours, but is <20 lines of code. ;-)