# Enumerated types documentation in 1.1 API

Tags: discussion, documentation, api-v1.1

I'm starting to implement requesting question and user activity in [my framework](https://stackapps.com/questions/346), but the new 1.1 API documentation doesn't seem to indicate what the possible return values are for the fields any more.

Where can I go to find this information?  (Specifically, I'm looking for the possible return values to the `timeline_type` and `action` keys)  I realize that I can just make a bunch of requests and try and figure this out myself, but this *should* be documented somewhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/enumerations ; which is now linked from the front page of the documentation as well.

Its very simplistic, but one of the nice behind the scenes changes in 1.1 was making it a lot easier for me to update the documentation.  Expect some better documentation on returned values in the not incredibly distance future.